# Python - 16X2 LCD display error loading driver without sudo

Tags: python, raspbian-stretch, lcd

I'm using Pi Zero/ Pi ZeroW with StrechLite to display an output on a 16X2 LCD display.

drivers was installed as instructed on [PiGuy official site](https://forum.dexterindustries.com/t/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied/414/2).

while running a sample code after installing - an error occurs:

```
guy@rpi2:~/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/lcd $ python3 demo_clock.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_clock.py", line 12, in <module>
    display = lcddriver.lcd()
  File "/home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/lcd/lcddriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.lcd_device = i2c_lib.i2c_device(ADDRESS)
  File "/home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/lcd/i2c_lib.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.bus = smbus.SMBus(port)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

But when using `sudo` it runs OK ([taken from here)](https://forum.dexterindustries.com/t/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied/414/2):

```
guy@rpi2:~/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/lcd $ sudo python3 demo_clock.py 
[sudo] password for guy: 
Writing to display

  [1]: https://www.theraspberrypiguy.com/raspberry-pi-mini-lcd-display-tutorial/
```

Any ideas how to solve it ?

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the recent Raspbian releases from raspberryi.org the pi user may be added as a member of the gpio, i2c, and spi groups, to grant access to those peripherals.

You don't mention the operating system you are using.

Try the following then logout and log back in for it to take effect.

`sudo adduser pi i2c`

Comment: I did mention : StrechLite

Comment: So you did.  I looked at the tags.

Comment: You are correct!